# Spring mixed XML/annotation configuration with overrides

Tags: spring

I'm working on setting up a utility that lets us load an annotation-based configuration that overrides an XML configuration (for testing). I have tried a number of different setups, but this is the only one that I've gotten to work:

```
GenericApplicationContext firstCtx = new GenericApplicationContext();

XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(firstCtx );
xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions("applicationContext.xml");

GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();

AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader annotatedReader = new AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);
annotatedReader.register(SomeConfigClass.class);

ctx.refresh();

for (String currBeanName : firstCtx.getBeanDefinitionNames())
{
    if (!ctx.containsBeanDefinition(currBeanName))
    {
        ctx.registerBeanDefinition(currBeanName, firstCtx.getBeanDefinition(currBeanName));
    }
}
```

While this technically does *work*, it seems like a really cumbersome way to do this. Is there a better way to load an annotation-based configuration over an XML-based configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way is to simply declare `SomeConfigClass` as a bean within your application context and the configured beans in SomeConfigClass will be wired in.

```
<bean class="..SomeConfigClass"/>
```

Or  `<context:component-scan base-package="package of SomeConfigClass"/>`

Or the other way round, in SomeClassClass, do `@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried the '@ImportResource' annotation, but unfortunately the XML would override the Annotation-based config. I considered doing component-scan, but that would require all tests to use the same overrides, and we want to be able to override individual beans on a per-test-class basis.